# Two selects to while function

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table which need to find all date and put the name just once (this is workig = $sql), but i have problem to select the that name of data and count how much time is repeats in same table. So where is name Test(down) there needs to be count for how much time that name repeats in whole table.

If I put one more while function the table dies.
Im stacked. Im not very good with php and mysql. If someone can help.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT one,two FROM results";
$sql2 = "select test, count(*) as foo_count from results group by test;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

<?php
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo "<tr><td>".$row["one"]."</td><td>".$row["two"]."</td><td>";}?> Test</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little bit of a hard time following your question, but I think you are looking for a single sql statement like this

```
$sql = "select test, count(one) as foo_count from results group by test";
```

Comment: I need that query in this select "$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT one,two FROM results"